# Mount Github link as docker volume

Tags: github, docker, bitbucket

Is there any way to mount github or other repo's http link as docker volumes, so that when I start my docker container, it would be running with the new code which I've pushed to github or bitbucket ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot *mount* such remote resources that are on the Internet.

What you can do is to have a shell script in your docker image which when executed will download those resources. And make docker run that script when the container is run.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY download-from-github.sh /
# your stuff...
RUN bash /download-from-github.sh
```

## download-from-github.sh

```
curl -sL https://github.com/you/repo/archive/master.zip > /tmp/master.zip
unzip /tmp/master.zip -d /opt
```

Comment: Thank You. Hope I can do the same to run my  containers in AWS.